# Как узнать версию Mozilla Firefox Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox

Как узнать версию фаер фокс на примонтированным диске? Где находиться конфигурацинный файл браузера.

Answer (score 2):

Версия есть в файле конфигурации:

```
/путь/к/диску/usr/lib/firefox/application.ini
```